# open_basedir, File() is not within the allowed path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, permissions, open-basedir

I'm having an issue with Laravel, installed on a Media Temple DV:

```
tempnam(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/:/tmp/)
```

This is the code that is giving this issue:

```
if (empty($this->cookie_file)) {
    $this->cookie_file = tempnam("", "phrets");
}
```

I'm thinking that it might be a permissions thing, but I'm really not too sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to add directory you use form `tempnam` into `open_basedir` or ask your server adminsitrator to turn it off ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir))

Comment: Yeah, I've been doing this and all kinds of other things ... seems that I needed to turn the setting off within Plesk.