# PHP FFMPEG open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg, centos

I have trouble with ffmpeg. If I want to create a thumb from a video I get the following error-message:

> file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/frame59c41921d102f6.99590608.jpg) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/faplink.net/public_html:/home/admin/tmp)

Code:

```
$video_thumb_path = "thumbs/" . md5($request->file("file")->getClientOriginalName() . time()) . ".png";
          $mov = new \ffmpeg_movie(storage_path("app/public/") . $post->media);
          $frame = $mov->getFrame(10);
          if ($frame) {
              $gd_image = $frame->toGDImage();
              if ($gd_image) {
                  imagepng($gd_image, $video_thumb_path);
                  imagedestroy($gd_image);
                  $post->thumb = $video_thumb_path;
              }
          }
          break;
```

I Use CentOS7

Comment: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26419085/4881811) it's the same thing !!

Comment: i don't know where i can change tempnam ...

Comment: Have you access to the server configuration file (e.g. httpd.conf) ??

Comment: You need to modify or disable the `open_basedir` directive in your PHP configuration file (`php.ini`) as mentioned in the answer to [open_basedir, File() is not within the allowed path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411683/open-basedir-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-path), or use a path that is listed in `open_basedir`.